# Custom font +text field place holder and text

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

hi all i facing  a strange problem in my app i have text field  i have to make custom font and color for text Field place holder .custom font working fine for text field text but one problem is that while entering text text going top of the text field .and one thing is there any delegate method which should call every click on clear key on keyboard .[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the position of the text i think you need to set:
`textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;`,
i don't know for the custom font of the placeholder.